# Javascript to php prevent modifications

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a little game inside an html-page which runs completely under JavaScript. When the game is finished I want to save the score of the player into a database using php. It would be something like:

```
/savescore.php?user=John+Doe&Score=1234
```

Because this is called from within the JavaScript I cannot really limit operations on the referer. How can I prevent users from just sending any score they want?

jQuery is in use, if needed.

Obfuscation is NOT a valid option for me in this case.

Comment: you can't completely do it, but you can use a XSRF or CSRF token.

Comment: also - don't use GET. use POST.

Comment: You can find more info about how to do it, here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40015/how-do-i-protect-sending-scores-from-html5-games-to-my-server

Comment: Also, if possible, keep saving score as the user plays, and yes use POST call

Answer (score 0):

You can't really. You can only make it more and more difficult until the vast majority of would-be-hackers gives up.